# DI with command pattern

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a service which acts to create and dispatch commands for execution.  It can either write commands to queue for deferred processing, or execute them immediately.

For these purposes I have something like:

```
class MyService
{
    private ICommandQueueWriter _commandQueueWriter;
    private ICommandExecutor _commandExecutor;

    public MyService(ICommandQueueWriter cqw, ICommandExecutor ce)
    {
        _commandQueueWriter = cqr;
        _commandExecutor = ce;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _commandQueueWriter.Write(new SomeCommand());
        _commandExecutor.Execute(new SomeOtherCommand());
    }
}
```

The service will deal with all kinds of commands.  I have a series of `ICommandHandler<>` implementations which will be registered with a DI container.

My plan has a flaw currently: the `ICommandExecutor` implementation needs to have access to all of the `ICommandHandler<>` implementations.  In fact, I guess the queued command execution will face the same problem: I'll grab the message later and have to look up the handler somehow.

So my options that I can see are:

1. Don't use `ICommandExecutor` as a dependency, just use `ICommandHandler<>`s directly.  But I wanted the option of wrapping all command handler execution through a standard class - to catch exceptions in a consistent way, or manage execution in some other consistent way.  I really like the option of having a consistent interface for immediate/deferred execution (either call Write or Execute)
2. Pass the DI container or root into `ICommandExecutor` and let it resolve commands.  This seems to break the idea that there should be one call to compose an object graph with DI, and might 'hide' dependencies
3. Have the implementation of `ICommandExecutor` have all `ICommandHandler<>`s as a dependency to be injected - so it can pick the one it wants manually.  However that doesn't seem ideal either, since all handlers on the system would be instantiated at that point

Is there are fourth option or do I need to bite the bullet with one of these compromises?

Comment: I don't quite see the problem. How does your `ICommandExecutor` implementation looks like currently? What is `ICommandHandler<>` and how it is used. Showing the implementation of `ICommandExecutor` will help, because you say problem is there.

Comment: This is conceptual currently.  The problem is that ICommandExecutor needs to resolve ICommandHandler<> to its implementation, but it doesn't know in advance which command types are required to be handled.  It's a conceptual DI issue.  Also, I thought it went without saying, but ICommandHandler<> is a generic interface for handlers of commands..?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: For a discussion about this model, read [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91).

Answer (score 3):

To me the use of both a `ICommandQueueWriter` and `ICommandExecutor` seems strange. Why should the consumer (`MyService` in your case) have to know that one command is queued, while another is executed directly. I think this should be transparent.

> Have the implementation of ICommandExecutor have all
>   ICommandHandler<>s as a dependency to be injected

This will cause severe maintenance problems, because you will add new command handlers very regularly and this will cause you to have to update the command executor's constructor every time.

Although you could also inject a collection of command handlers, this would still force you to iterate the list every time you want to execute one to get the correct implementation. This will get slower over time, because you will add new command handlers regularly.

> Pass the DI container or root into ICommandExecutor and let it resolve
>   commands. This seems to break the idea that there should be one call
>   to compose an object graph with DI, and might 'hide' dependencies

It might seem that you are applying the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) if you do this, but this is only the case if the `ICommandExecutor` is part of the application code. The trick is to make the `ICommandExecutor` part of your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). This [solves the problem](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/) because the composition root will already be very tightly coupled to your container.

Comment: Thanks, very useful and that kind of sits well and puts the formal name to something that was a bit slippery to me.  Interested in a quick follow-up on your first point - when you say client, you mean the service?  In this case the service is planned as a facade to abstract the use of commands and how they are dispatched.  My thinking: one service call might send 20,000 email notifications, another might result in a single field being updated, needing acknowledgement before the caller returns.  Would you suggest both an immediate command, one command deferring work in some other way?

Comment: I read again, see what you mean about the client needing to know.  I would say that they shouldn't need to know: they'd just work to the API and the system would handle that detail.  Can't immediately think of an example where this falls down? - but would welcome one

Comment: Thanks for your article.I just wanted to make a note that moving many components to Composition Root is a code smell. You should work hard to avoid it, use it only when you can't find any solution.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel is right. Your Composition Root should only contain infrastructural logic, no application logic (such as business and presentation logic).

Answer (score 0):

> Have the implementation of ICommandExecutor have all ICommandHandler<>s as a dependency to be injected - so it can pick the one it wants manually. However that doesn't seem ideal either, since all handlers on the system would be instantiated at that point

If you want to inject handlers, but don't want handlers to be instantiated at injection time, then

1. Inject into command executor a collection of lazy instantiated handlers with metadata containing command type.

Like,

```
IEnumerable(of Lazy(of ICommandHandler, ICommandHandlerMetadata))
```

where `ICommandExecutorMetadata` contains command type corresponding to command handler

```
public interface ICommandHandlerMetadata
    readonly property CommandType as Type
end interface
```

2. In command executor transform the collection into a dictionary of pairs `(Type, Lazy(of ICommandHandler, ICommandHandlerMetadata))`, where `Type` is command type obtained from metadata through `Lazy.Metadata.CommandType`.
3. In `CommandExecutor.Execute` method lazy initiated command handler is obtained from the dictionary by command type. This operation is ultra fast. The actual `CommandHandler` is obtained through `Lazy.Value`.

Actual `CommandHandler` is instantiated only once and exactly when a corresponding command is executed.